# printf's floating point format flag (%f) for English number format only

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, floating-point, printf

I'm writing data into a file that can be opened on multiple computers. The issue is that when I format floating point numbers with the "%f" formatting flag, `printf` variants of the function (`wprintf`, `CString::Format`, `StringCchPrintf`, etc.) make it locale specific.

For instance:

```
double f = 1.5;
WCHAR buff[256];
StringCchPrintf(buff, 256, L"%f", f);
```

will output `"1.5"` for US-English but then may output `"1,5"` for some European locales, etc.

So I'm curious if there's a flag other than `%f` that will output a floating point number in one format only? (Preferably English.)

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: So what do you do? Write your own conversion routine from float to string, or change & restore locale before every `printf` call?

Comment: Write a function wrapping printf  that does  change and restore of locale transparently. Or change the locale once at the start of your program.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this question is tagged C++: use the formatting from `std::num_put`  and `std::numpunct` for the `”C”`  locale. The easiest way to do so is by using a suitable `std::ostream` and `imbue()`ing `std::locale::classic()`.

A comment suggest to write an own conversion function: I’d recommend against doing so as implementing this conversion correctly is non-trivial. See [*How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately*](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/gcl-devel/2012-10/pdfkieTlklRzN.pdf).

Comment: If you are referring to my comment, I didn't suggest re-writing printf, which as you say would be a major undertaking, I suggested wrapping it to manage changes in locale.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: MikeF asked about “Write your own conversion routine from float to string”.

Answer (score 1):

you need call [`setlocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale) or [`_wsetlocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale) before call `StringCchPrintf` or say `_snwprintf`. for example:

```
    WCHAR buf[32];
    double f = 1.5;

    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "english");
    _snwprintf(buf, RTL_NUMBER_OF(buf), L"%f", f);
    // 1.500000
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "German");
    _snwprintf(buf, RTL_NUMBER_OF(buf), L"%f", f);
    // 1,500000
```

or as alternative can use [`StringCchPrintf_l`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh305639(v=vs.85).aspx) or another **_l** functions. but in this case you need call [`_create_locale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/create-locale-wcreate-locale) and [`_free_locale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/free-locale)

```
    WCHAR buf[32];
    double f = 1.5;
    _locale_t locale;

    if (locale = _create_locale(LC_NUMERIC, "German"))
    {
        _snwprintf_l(buf, RTL_NUMBER_OF(buf), L"%f", locale, f);
        _free_locale(locale);
        // 1,500000
    }

    if (locale = _create_locale(LC_NUMERIC, "english"))
    {
        _snwprintf_l(buf, RTL_NUMBER_OF(buf), L"%f", locale, f);
        _free_locale(locale);
        // 1.500000
    }
```

we can use for example next [Language Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/39cwe7zf(v=vs.100).aspx). however exist multiple ways to use locale strings

Comment: `setlocale` (by default) sets the locale for all threads in a process, thereby changing the runtime behavior of threads you do not own. [SetThreadLocale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051.aspx) is a better option. Alternatively, enable per-thread locale settings with [_configthreadlocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/configthreadlocale).

Comment: @IInspectable - alternatively we can create locale via  `_create_locale` and explicit use it, as i and show in code

Comment: I was commenting on the first solution you proposed, which is less than ideal, and will introduce subtle (and not so subtle) bugs. If you must change the locale, then do it for the calling thread only. Not changing the locale at all is usually a better idea. Showing a second solution alone doesn't fix the issues with the first solution, though.

Comment: @IInspectable - this depend from - which code call `setlocale`. if code from exe - this is ok. exe code have right do this. if from generic dll - this already not ok, and can really affect process.

Comment: This isn't OK to call from an EXE either. It changes the environment of threads you do not own or control. I have explained what the issue is, and proposed 2 ways to address it.

Comment: @IInspectable - but who own the process ? i think that exe code have right change global process state.  and exe code decide which threads will be created, which task they will be done. with system working pool threads here also no problem. if in process exist some 3-rd party injected threads - this is already they problem care about locale, may be by explicit use it in foreign process

Comment: may be in process will be created multiple threads and at startup (before create this threads) exe code can want set locale for all thread at once. exe code have right to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in program:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

Or set environment variable before program starts:

```
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8";
```